# React Append a button on radio button selection

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to append a button on the selection of a radio button. I understand I have to play with states in order to achieve this but this is complicated for me. Please help.

Comment: Share some code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the React docs [doc1](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) [doc2](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) [doc3](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Try this:

```
class Radio extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {radio: 0};
    this.onRadioChanged = this.onRadioChanged.bind(this);
  }

  onRadioChanged(event) {
      this.setState({radio: parseInt(event.target.value, 10)});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <input type="radio"
        value={0} 
        checked={this.state.radio === 0} 
        onChange={this.onRadioChanged} />
      Option 1
      <input type="radio"
        value={1} 
        checked={this.state.radio === 1} 
        onChange={this.onRadioChanged} />
      Option 2
      {this.state.radio === 1? <button>Hi!</button> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(
    <Radio/>, 
    document.body
);
```